# Revolver.js IE 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

IE9 is throwing "Object doesn't support property or method 'revolver' " error - other browsers are working correctly - javascripts are entered in a good order i think - and i do not use prototype or more jquery versions as well.

My code:

```
<!-- latest jQuery  -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery.js" />
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajaxhelper.js"></script>
<!-- JScrollPane mousewheel plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jscrollpane/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<!-- JScrollPane script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jscrollpane/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js">                         
</script>
<!-- Revolver.js -->
<script type="text/javascript "src="js/revolver/jquery.revolver.min.js"></script>
```

And my ajaxhelper class:

```
function getProject(id){
$.ajax(
{
    type    : "POST",
    url     : "projects.php",
    data    : {
        "project-id" : id,
        "action" : "image"
    },
    success : function(response)
    {                      

        $(".imagesection").empty();

        $(".imagesection").append(response);

        var revolver = $('#my-slider').revolver({ ... }).data('revolver');

}
```

I am appending the "my-slider" , and calling the revolver function on it - theres where IE9 stops.

Comment: So far I have not been able to reproduce this. Would you mind recreating your error in a jsfiddle or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML HEAD block, change

```
<script type="text/javascript "src="js/revolver/jquery.revolver.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/revolver/jquery.revolver.min.js"></script>
```

Notice where the double quote is after `text/javascript`? :P

Answer (score 2):

i found this

https://github.com/johnnyfreeman/revolver/issues/7

looks like a known issue with ie9.

Comment: The cause of that issue was because the script was being loading directly from Github's servers. That doesn't seem to be the case here.